# Removing an Autofilter that is set by variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some trouble removing an autofilter that is set by a variable. I have tried everything I could think of/find online. Nothing seems to be able to remove it. Any suggestions?

```
Dim CashRange As Range
Set CashRange = Range("L2:L50000")
CashRange.AutoFilter 1, "CASH"
CashLabeledRows = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
CashRange.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
CashRange.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: This works at my end. What issues are you having? Do you have errors?

Comment: No errors. I can't get the autofilter to remove from the column. All the data is displayed but it still shows that it is being filtered. I have to manually click the filter button in excel to actually remove it, although using an ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False does not work.

Comment: `All the data is displayed but it still shows that it is being filtered` I cannot re-produce this. If all data is displayed then `AutoFilter` is removed. Are you working on a normal range and not a table range?

Comment: Works on my end too. You can get rid of AutoFilter using different approach by replacing `CashRange.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False` with `CashRange.AutoFilter`. Give this a try. If you are still having issues with it, we will need a better description of the issue, maybe a link to screenshot.

Comment: @L42 - I am working on a normal range. No table. Is it possible to be showing in the UI that a filter is being applied but isn't actually? That's the only explanation I can come up with.

Comment: @Branislav Kollár - I tried that and it is doing the same thing. I'm beginning to think the filter is just doing something strange in the UI.

Comment: @whoami Maybe you are right. I cannot reproduce the issue. I have a few questions for you to investigate. **Q1** : When this "persistent autofilter" is in place, are you able to click on the dropdown arrow symbol and the filter list menu pops up? **Q2** : What is your `Application.ScreenUpdating` setting? Please set it to `true`. **Q3** : Can you try swithcing worksheets to another and back to the one with filters? If it's just wrong UI behaviour, this could help. **Q4** : When you close and reopen the workbook, are the filter arrows symbols still in place?

Comment: @Branislav Kollár - 

**1)** I am able to view the filter list menu. Nothing is filtered but the filter is applied.

**2)** ScreenUpdating is set to true and I tried alternating the values but that did not fix it. 

**3)** Switching worksheets did not remove the autofilter or allow vba to remove it. 

**4)** Closing and reopening the workbook also did not remove the autofilter or allow it to be removed via vba.

Comment: @Branislav Kollár - After further testing, in other situations it does filter the data. It seems only single entries have the filter applied but it does not filter. Any ideas?

Comment: @whoami, can you please update your original post with this new information? And please differenciate between **Filter arrow symbol** (just the arrow in headers, but no rows are filtered), **Filter applied** (some criteria added to the filter and values are filtered = hidden rows). Thank you.

Comment: @Branislav Kollár - I resolved the issue by skipping the code if the value was not present. Thanks for all the help. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the optimal answer but after some testing over different data types present in the form, I determined that the filter issue was only present when "CASH" was not present in any cell of the L column.

I decided the best way to combat this for the time being was to do a FIND on the column for the CASH value. Then based on the response, I had a GoTo defined for before and after the above vba. Basically skipping if it was unnecessary.

Thanks everyone for your time and input. Code posted below for reference.

```
Dim t As Range
Set t = Columns("L").Find("CASH", LookAt:=xlWhole)
If t Is Nothing Then
        GoTo AfterCashYellow
    ElseIf Not t Is Nothing Then
        GoTo CashYellowFill
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this examples, maybe they will be helpfull.

```
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then 'checks if there are any filters turned on!?
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then 'if there are filters at all(what so ever)
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData  'Turns off all filters(select all), but not remove them
```

This is not sequence code, Every line is just for it self. But it can be combined with each other.

Comment: I tried something along those lines initially before I posted but with no luck.